# Reading xml file with linq and getting error : Invalid character in the given encoding

Tags: c#, xml, linq

this way i am reading a xml file with linq and getting error `Invalid character in the given encoding`

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"c:\users\tridip\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication5\WindowsFormsApplication5\Orders.xml");
            var books = from r in document.Descendants("book")
            select new
            {
                OrderID = r.Element("OrderID").Value,
                CustomerID = r.Element("CustomerID").Value,
                EmployeeID = r.Element("EmployeeID").Value,
            };
```

i have see this kind of data in xml

```
<Orders>
    <OrderID>10249</OrderID>
    <CustomerID>TOMSP</CustomerID>
    <EmployeeID>6</EmployeeID>
    <OrderDate>1996-07-05T00:00:00</OrderDate>
    <RequiredDate>1996-08-16T00:00:00</RequiredDate>
    <ShippedDate>1996-07-10T00:00:00</ShippedDate>
    <ShipVia>1</ShipVia>
    <Freight>11.6100</Freight>
    <ShipName>Toms Spezialitäten</ShipName>
    <ShipAddress>Luisenstr. 48</ShipAddress>
    <ShipCity>Münster</ShipCity>
    <ShipPostalCode>44087</ShipPostalCode>
    <ShipCountry>Germany</ShipCountry>
  </Orders>
```

see this `<ShipName>Toms Spezialitäten</ShipName>` there are some invalid or unknown character in text. how to get rid of this. i want to read xml if there exist unknown character in xml data. please guide me what to add in my above code to handle this situation. thanks

### issue solved

the moment i add encoding in my xml data like this way the it started working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
  <Orders>
    <OrderID>10248</OrderID>
    <CustomerID>VINET</CustomerID>
    <EmployeeID>5</EmployeeID>
    <OrderDate>1996-07-04T00:00:00</OrderDate>
    <RequiredDate>1996-08-01T00:00:00</RequiredDate>
    <ShippedDate>1996-07-16T00:00:00</ShippedDate>
    <ShipVia>3</ShipVia>
    <Freight>32.3800</Freight>
    <ShipName>Vins et alcools Chevalier</ShipName>
    <ShipAddress>59 rue de l'Abbaye</ShipAddress>
    <ShipCity>Reims</ShipCity>
    <ShipPostalCode>51100</ShipPostalCode>
    <ShipCountry>France</ShipCountry>
  </Orders>

<Orders>
   .... more data
</Orders>
</Root>

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"c:\users\tridip\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication5\WindowsFormsApplication5\Orders.xml");
            var books = from r in document.Descendants("Orders")
            select new
            {
                OrderID = r.Element("OrderID").Value,
                CustomerID = r.Element("CustomerID").Value,
                EmployeeID = r.Element("EmployeeID").Value,
            };

          dataGridView1.DataSource=  books.ToList();
        }
```

Comment: I think I asked you this before, but try to search first, try to include what you have researched in your question and start your sentences with a Capital. Anyway see duplicate or [any](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275825/) [of](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939946/) [the](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14281408/) [many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829715/) [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455335/) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854335/) about this very issue. It's got to do with encodings, try reading the file in the encoding it's wirtten.

Comment: which encoding i should follow. plzz give me hint so i can search google with right keyword.

Comment: You need to read the file in the encoding it's written. Very likely to be UTF-8. Any of the six linked questions show you how to read XML in a different encoding. No need to Google that, just read the questions and understand the problem you're having.

Comment: thanks all. issue solved. i updated my post.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include your solution. The correct approach here on Stackoverflow is to write an answer.

Comment: the relevant button did not come to add my answer.